# Error: write EPIPE trying to setup shopify app

Tags: node.js, next.js, shopify, shopify-app, ngrok

I tried to install a shopify app in my development store. I used both the manual way (https://shopify.dev/tutorials/build-a-shopify-app-with-node-and-react/embed-your-app-in-shopify) as the CLI way (https://shopify.github.io/shopify-app-cli/getting-started/).

I keep getting this `Error: write EPIPE at WriteWrap.onWriteComplete [as oncomplete] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:16)`

I don't know what I'm doing wrong and why I can't find any solution on that error. Am I really the only one facing this problem?

Comment: At what point are you getting the error? What's triggering it?

Comment: It's triggered when trying to access the ngrok domain. I think it was the 60 connections / minute limit. But I found the solution... I paid for ngrok and now it's working.. as always its all about the benjamins! But thats fine, I like their service anyway. Nevertheless they could tell or at least mention that in the tutorials

Comment: I see the same error even with the Ngrok Business plan, must be something else

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Comment: for me, it was my ISP. I think the IP address assigned to my machine by my ISP wasn't working right with ngrok. Changing to a different ISP solve the problem for me.